# Update SQL table with values to update and values to compare both in separate comma delimited strings

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have a SQL table where I need to update `Date` field of multiple Users. The primary key (`userId`) field is int. Now I am sending the `Date` values in a comma separated string (like "10/06/2013,12/05/2013,16/07/2013") and corresponding `userId` values also in a comma separated string (like "1001,1002,1005").

How can I update all relevant Users in my stored procedure? Or should I send the `userId`s and `Date`s in any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
   DECLARE @dates VARCHAR(8000)   = '10/06/2013,12/05/2013,16/07/2013'    
    DECLARE @userid VARCHAR(8000)   = '1001,1002,1005'    

    DECLARE @t1 TABLE
        (
          dates VARCHAR(50) ,
          userid VARCHAR(50)
        )

    WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @dates) > 0 
        BEGIN



            INSERT  INTO @t1
                    ( dates ,
                      userid 
                    )
            VALUES  ( SUBSTRING(@dates, 1, ( CHARINDEX(',', @dates) - 1 )) ,
                      SUBSTRING(@userid, 1, ( CHARINDEX(',', @userid) - 1 ))
                    )

            SET @dates = SUBSTRING(@dates, CHARINDEX(',', @dates) + 1,
                                   LEN(@dates))

            SET @userid = SUBSTRING(@userid, CHARINDEX(',', @userid) + 1,
                                    LEN(@userid))

        END
    INSERT  INTO @t1
            ( dates, userid )
    VALUES  ( @dates, @userid )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    @t1 AS t

    UPDATE  LMS.dbo.Employee
    SET     JoiningDate = ( SELECT  dates
                            FROM    @t1 AS t
                            WHERE   LMS.dbo.Employee.Code = t.userid
                          )
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be good if you send a XML including date and user id. That is comparatively faster as well.

Answer (score 0):

That is what prepared statements are for. Create a prepared `UPDATE` statement. And then execute it with different values as many times as you need.